# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width')

Tags: react-native

```
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.box}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={require('../images/pic.png')}
            >
                <Icon
                  type='foundation'
                  name='dump'
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
            </ImageBackground>

            <Text style={styles.text}>
            Hello
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hi, I keep getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width') error when using imagebackground. Why is this occuring?

Answer (score 4):

This is from the RN docs for imageBackground and it says you should add height and width to image background for it to work.

> Note that you must specify some width and height style attributes.

So just replace your code with the following :

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.box}>
                <ImageBackground
                  source={require('../images/pic.png')}
                  style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} // new addition
                >
                    <Icon
                      type='foundation'
                      name='dump'
                      style={styles.icon}
                    />
                </ImageBackground>

                <Text style={styles.text}>
                Hello
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [react-native ImageBackground documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground#example) you must specify some width and height style attributes. So you have to add `width` and `height` value of it's styles.

example :

```js
<ImageBackground 
    source={require('../images/pic.png')} 
    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} //add this
>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native documentation says the `style` property for the `ImageBackground` component is **not required**. However, there seems to be an ongoing issue, as it only works if you **do** include the `style` prop. Try sending a value for it, that should solve the issue.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18904